# Filter a Dictionary<String,List<String>>

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<String, List<String>>` and I need to filter it, and and leave only those pairs where the `List<String>` contains values that are repeated (duplicates). I understand that there should be a linq subquery but all my variants fail.

Example:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<String,List<String>>();

dictionary.Add("Key1", new List<String>{"1","2","2","3"});
dictionary.Add("Key2", new List<String>{"1","2","3"});
dictionary.Add("Key3", new List<String>{"1","2","4"});
dictionary.Add("Key4", new List<String>{"1","2","5"});
```

So I need to leave only first pair, because that list has duplicates for the value "2".

Comment: You may want to provide example input and expected output data. It is hard to tell if the duplicate is in a single list or across lists.

Comment: @JohnMcCann Thank you for the advice.

Comment: You could use distinct to create another list, then compare your list against it to exclude rows which match..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of your dictionary:

- take all key-value-pairs
- of those, take only the ones where the list after removal of duplicates no longer has the same number of elements (so there *were* duplicates)
- and then create a new dictionary from the remaining key-value-pairs

---

Code:

```
var filteredDictionary = dictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value.Distinct().Count()
                                               != pair.Value.Count)
                                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: I like your approach. I was trying to use GroupBy with Count() > 1. Your solution is easier.

Comment: a huge thank you! Now I understand the  linq logic better